# What are the musical sounds that are heard from garbage trucks called?

Tags: word-choice

Garbage trucks have devices that make musical sounds attached to them and I am unable to locate the term. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a specific name for those melodies (I know them well, and hated them as they used to wake me up twice a week when I lived in Kanagawa-ken :) ).

They also seem not to be a standard, but to depend on the area and the specific town/neighborhood.

[This](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%94%E3%81%BF%E5%8F%8E%E9%9B%86%E8%BB%8A) Wikipedia article simply refers to them as 電子音{でんしおん}のメロディ ( "electronic melody"). In particular, quote:

> また、日本の一部の地方自治体やアジア諸国などでは、周りの人々に気付いてもらいやすいように、電子音のメロディを鳴らしながらごみを回収する事例もある

[This](http://www.o-uccino.jp/article/archive/omoshiro/063_20151215_gomi/) is another article that explains how these melodies really seem to depend on the area and town (as well as the fact that the trucks make a sound at all). Also in this article, I don't seem to find any specific word to describe this sound. It is broadly referred to as 音楽{おんがく}.

This article also report some commonly used melodies such as: 「赤とんぼ」,「草競馬」,「乙女の祈り」, and 「エリーゼのために」 (some of these are also referred in the Wikipedia article above).

Answer (score 0):

So do the forklifts  or other heavy machinery at some works or factories to get people's awareness.

I didn't know the specific term for the music so I looked up and got this.[image]

The questioner uses '前進メロディー' , which totally makes sense to me in this context but like the answer goes it's not  a common word.